# Decrypting Network Packets of Counter Strike 1.6

Tags: security, networking, encryption, game-engine

I'm trying to decrypt network packets sent and received during gameplay of Counter Strike 1.6 to understand network flow and game states for purpose of game security. Can anyone give suggestions as to what would be the best way of doing so?

For example:
An the encrypted string within a packet is: **1T[wWR8jfTSA}K9ShnSIi'3[XRPR!S3S[_XvS(b>SGe:PBMZOCqG}L**

A possible candidate for my key is:
**1b5337d0c8ad813197b506146d8d503d**

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the point of encryption. You can't decrypt it without the keys.

Comment: Even if I had the keys, is there any way I could figure out which algorithm to use?

Answer (score 0):

Start by either (A) creating a proxy or (B) use a packet capture application (i.e Wireshark) to capture traffic from your client to the server.  Then determine the type of "secure communication" begin used (i.e. TLS).  Then you should be able to create a middleman (proxy) that can decrypt the session in real-time (during gameplay) and view application states (i.e. other player's position).  If proxy and/or WireShark does not reveal the type of secure communication, then author is using proprietary encryption...  If that's true, then you MAY be able to determine the "type of encryption".

The above encrypted data is not STRING, but rather a series BINARY BYTES, whose length is 56 bytes (not a common digest or block size modulo).  The key you provided is 32 bytes (256-bit), so this could be used as valid AES-256 key. Try posting the complete packet and I can provide some more details.

Comment: how can proxy be implemented?

Comment: You can find a capture of a few packets here: https://ufile.io/5853t (Its a wireshark capture)

Comment: can counter administrator(server) run script on client(my pc) ? CS 1.6 is Safe ?